# Yii2 delete cache by variations

Tags: caching, yii2

I just want to flush cache by variations, for example just flush the cache with variations id 5

I did't find any reference about flush params ..
thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to flush cache by variation, at least not in any standardized way (implementation would differ for different cache storages, and for some of them this could be impossible). However you can invalidate caches using [`TagDependency`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-caching-tagdependency) - after calling `TagDependency::invalidate()` old cache still will be stored in cache storage, but it will be discarded on `Cache::get()` call.

Comment: Thank you do you have some example ? i have to test it

Comment: and do you know any way to prevent cache for some dependcy ? for example I dont wnat to cache page cash for all pages in single action

Comment: You may inject something like https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-caching-dummycache as cache component for this action.

Comment: There is a bug in the Yii2 since years. Removing cache entries by setting an tag invalid, with `TagDependency::invalidate()`  is "currently" (since 2018) not working. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77000495/644817

Answer (score 1):

I could not implement through `TagDependency::invalidate()`.
But I was able to find another solution.
So, if you caching like this (in templates):

```
$this->beginCache('someKey', ['variations' => [$param1, $param2]]);
```

You can easy delete this cache from another place like this:

```
Yii::$app->cache->delete(['yii\widgets\FragmentCache', 'someKey', $param1, $param2]);
```